# Shopping Cart Price rule defination for Product Category

Tags: php, magento, shopping-cart, magento-1.8

I wanted to define shopping cart price rule for selected categories. Like total amount to selected categories are more than 50$, Shipping is free.

I tried with following Shopping Cart Price Rule. Its not working, any idea?

```
   If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
If total amount  equals or greater than  50 for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions:
    Category  is not one of  6,7
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
    If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true: 
        Category  is not one of  6,7  
        Price in cart  equals or greater than  50
```